# How to enable Pole in BigBlueButton Moodle?

Tags: moodle, bigbluebutton

I install the **BigBlueButton** plugin in my **Moodle**. It is working fine. In tutorials it said that there is `pole` option. But I can't see how to add a pole using `BigBlueButton`. How to enable the `Pole` in `BigBlueButton`? In `menu bar` there is only **Share desktop, Audio, Web cam option**. There is no `Pole` option.

I am using **Moodle 2.7** and **BigBlueButton 1.0.11**

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the core developers of BigBlueButton.

There is no polling module available (yet) for BigBlueButton; it is definitely on our roadmap.

> I am using Moodle 2.7 and BigBlueButton 1.0.11

The latest version of BigBlueButton (at the time of this message) is BigBlueButton 0.9.0-beta.

Comment: BigBlueButton 1.0 has polling.  See http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/overview/overview.html#polling